# Tkinter Freely transition between windows?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-button

OK so I don't feel like rebuilding my program from the ground up yet again. So I'm not going to be changing 10 different Tk() objects into top levels until it benefits me to do so. What I'm wondering. I will he focusing on transitioning from window 1 to 2 and back and back again.

```
from tkinter import *
Window1 = Tk()
Window2 = Tk()

Window1.title('first window')
Window1.geometry("800x800")

def Window_2():
   Window1.withdraw()
   Window2.title('Second Window')
   Window2.geometry("800x800")
   Button2.pack()
   Window2.mainloop()
....
....

Button1 = Button(Window1, text = 'Go to 2', command = Window_2)
Button2 = Button(Window2, text = 'Go to 1', command = lambda: [Window2.withdraw(), Window1.deiconify()])
Button1.pack()
Window1.mainloop()
```

I would like to be able to go back and forth between the windows freely with one closing and the other opening.  When I run this I can get to window2 and back to 1 just fine but then window 2 is just a black screen on the next iteration. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit.  If you copy paste this it works like I said just delete the 2 lines of ....

Comment: Having more instances of `Tk` than one is unnecessary and if you had used classes you would've easily exchanged the base-class in order to achieve this. Refactoring code is part of the development, you should get used to it. Also, you might use the same window and just exchange frames by pack and pack_forget.

Comment: I have to agree with Thingamabob: you're starting out with the wrong architecture, so telling you the right way to do it with the current architecture will be very difficult. Why do you need multiple root windows rather than a single root window with multiple additional `Toplevel` windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Window2.deiconify()` instead of `Window2.mainloop()` inside `Window_2()` to show the *hidden* `Window2`.

As said in comments, it is better to use `Toplevel()` instead for child windows and need to call `mainloop()` only once.

```py
def Window_2():
   Window1.withdraw()
   Window2.title('Second Window')
   Window2.geometry("800x800")
   Button2.pack()
   Window2.deiconify() # for showing back Window2 if it is hidden
   # don't need to call mainloop() here
```

Also suggest to call `Window2.withdraw()` after creating `Window2` to make it hidden initially.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a bit of code below. You will see I am taking advice on using toplevel.  But I am now stuck again.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('change text')
Label1 = Label(root, text = 'Change me')
Label1.pack()

def presto():
    Label1.configure(entry1.get())

def open_sub():
    top1 = Toplevel(root)
    top1.title('Buttons')
    label1 = Label(top1, text = 'Type Something')
    entry1 = Entry(top1, width = 20)
    button1 = Button(top1, text = "execute", command = presto)
    button2 = Button(top1, text = 'close', command = top1.destroy)
    label1.pack()
    entry1.pack()
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()

button1 = Button(root, text = 'page 2', command = open_sub)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I know thus is unrelated, but it does display the answer to the original question. The new problem exist when trying to change the label.  I get error code:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1948, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 9, in presto
Label1.configure(entry1.get())
^^^^^^
NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined

And I can't pull Entry 1 out of the toplevel function because then I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/temp_iiec_codefile.py", line 8, in 
entry1 = Entry(top1, width = 20)
^^^^
NameError: name 'top1' is not defined

I'm literally just showing progress and an unrelated problem that probably wont be solved in this thread. I don't want to delete the original problem because this shows a solution and someone else might find it useful.

Comment: You should update your question with these new information instead of posting them as answer.

Comment: Then you should raise another question instead.